# Is there a way to get all pagination links at time in facebook page/feed api

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api

Is there way to get all pagination links at time in facebook page/feed api

I want to get all facebook page/feed pagination links at once.. is it possible?
I don't want to wait until current fetch is done and then I get next page link.

I have tried with date range way, which is the one solution i found so far.

`page_id/feed?since=2014-01-01&until=2014-02-02&limit=100`.

is there any better way to get all pagination links at once without missing any post.

My intention is to fetch these links in asynchronous way.

Comment: I believe that the whole idea of paginating results is to not allow users to make massive calls to their API. Making multiple simultaneous requests would also constitute massive calls...

Comment: Oh! but is it possible if i try with different access token for request?

Comment: Yes - it is possible but you are not guaranteed to get exactly 100 results even if you specify the limit.

Comment: ...and using different access tokens to avoid any call limit is surely not allowed on facebook

Comment: hey guys thanks for your replies. So i have to fetch data in the way that facebook allows. :(